# implements onLongClickListener, onDragListener on android 2.x

Tags: android, api, onlongclicklistener

At first: I know that `onDrag` and `onLongClick` available only on API 11(android 3.0) or higher.

Class implements `onDragListener` and `onLonglickListener`. It's work only at API 11 and higher.
when I want set `setonLongclickListener` on `view` I use code like this:

```
 .....
 protected static final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
 ......
 ......
 if(sdk >= 11){ 
     for (int i = 0; i < LlayoutFront.getChildCount(); i++){ 
         LlayoutFront.getChildAt(i).setOnDragListener(this);
     }   
     LlayoutDeleteArea.setOnDragListener(this);
     LlayoutSetupArea.setOnDragListener(this);
     findViewById(R.id.RelativeLMain).setOnDragListener(this);
 }
```

but app crashed when i try to run it on `android 2.1`.

`@SuppressLint("NewApi")` before my Class isn't save my situation.

Any ideas?

Comment: You either remove the drag functionality on older API devices or create/port the drag system on older versions.

Comment: thx. I solve my problem. after 8 hour answer be here))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it ;)
remove implements method `onDragListener` and `onLongClickListener` from me Class.
and modify code like this:

```
if(sdk >= 11){ 
    for (int i = 0; i < LlayoutFront.getChildCount(); i++){
        LlayoutFront.getChildAt(i).setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {                 
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                return myOnDrag(v, event);
            }
        });
    }
    LlayoutDeleteArea.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {                  
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return myOnDrag(v, event);
        }
    });
    LlayoutSetupArea.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {                   
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return myOnDrag(v, event);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.RelativeLMain).setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {                   
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return myOnDrag(v, event);
        }
    });
}
```